# Can not allocate memory on archlinux

Tags: memory, arch-linux

I have a C program that uses lots of memory.

I also have AchLinux box with 32 GB RAM.

My program fail to allocate more than ~12 GB RAM, even I start it as root.

I checked `ulimit` but I did not found anything wrong there.

```
# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 124349
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 124349
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

---

If I run on my laptop (16 GB RAM), I can not allocate more than ~6 GB RAM. However I did not do lots of research there.

If I run on CentOS, I have no such problem.

Comment: Please, run the cmd **free -mh** after that your programa can't allocate memory, then copy and paste the free's output on your question.